# Why is Jersey/JAX-RS client unable to handle generics?

Tags: java, json, generics, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersery/JAX-RS client that hits a RESTful API (JSON) that is supposed to return a list of my POJOs:

```
// Hits: GET localhost:8080/myapp/fizz/widget/{widget_id}
@Override
public List<Widget> getWidgetsByUser(Long id) {
    return webResource.path("fizz").path("widget").path(id.toString()).get(List.class);
}
```

And a driver to test the client with:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Driver d = new Driver();
        d.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        MyAppService myService = getSomehow();

        List<Widget> widgets = myService.getWidgetResource().getWidgetsByUser(2L);
        for(Widget widget : widgets) {
            System.out.println("\t...and it found Widget #" + widget.getCaseId());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.me.myapp.Widget
    <stack trace omitted for brevity>
```

The exception is being thrown from the for-loop:

```
for(Widget widget : widgets) {
```

Which tells me the client is sort of working, but that I don't have it configured correctly.

So either Jersey is trying to return pure JSON and **isn't** attempting to map it back to a list of Widgets, or I am invoking the `get(Class<?>)` method incorrectly. Any ideas?

Comment: That is quite easy to understand - you are telling Jersey (probably with Jackson under it) to convert response body to `List`. What else can you expect from the framework to do than to just choose whatever the framework wants to use for the list elements.

Comment: Thanks @PavelHoral (+1) - so how do I configure Jersey to return a `List<Widget>`?

Comment: You can workaround the issue by introducting `WidgetCollection` object with the list as its property (that is a common practice I would say). Other from that I would go through Jersey documentation. But you might end up reading Jackson's approach to solving this (`TypeReference`) - however that would probably not play with Jersey's API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comment by Pavel Horal is correct. Without a known type, Jackson (the underlying deserilaizer) will map to `LinkedHashMap`, so it will return `List<LinkedHashMap>`

Fix:

For generic types, we should use the other [`get()` method](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#get%28com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType%29), which takes a [`GenericType`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/GenericType.html) argument. So we should do something like

```
...get(new GenericType<List<Widget>>(){});
```