# How to create proper JAXB mapping to make Jersey deserialization process happened

Tags: json, serialization, jersey, jax-rs, deserialization

I have JSON response from WS:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bobby",
    "status": "single"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "status": "married"
  }
]
```

Here is my wrapper

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
public class UserListWrapper {   

    private List<User> users;   

    @XmlElement(name = "user")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }    

    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

And User class

```
@XmlRootElement
class User {
    private String name;
    private String status;    

    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

The problem is when Jersey try to deserialize response to my wrapper object. It say

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.jersey.test.UserListWrapper out of START_ARRAY token
```

Seams that something wrong with my wrapper annotations. How can I fix them?

*UPD*

When I send

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "status": "single"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "status": "married"
    }
  ]
}
```

all works fine. But I need this format

```
[
  {
    "name": "Bobby",
    "status": "single"
  },
  ...
]
```

*UPD*

Jersey Client code

```
    HttpAuthenticationFeature authenticationFeature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("user", "secret");
    Client client = ClientBuilder
            .newClient()
            .register(authenticationFeature)
            .register(JacksonFeature.class);

    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/server/");
    UserListWrapper entity;
    Response resp;

    resp = target.queryParam("u", "info")
            .path("/rest/users")
            .request()
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get();


    entity = resp.readEntity(UserListWrapper.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the `UserListWrapper` wrapper then. `List<User>` is perfect for the JSON array ( `[]` ) format. If you add the wrapper class, then yes you will need the extra JSON object layer ( `{}` ). This:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createBook(List<User> users) {
```

is supported just fine (at least with Jackson - which you are using).

---

**UPDATE**

If the response from the server is coming as a JSON array, then you can still deserialize it as a `List<User>`. For example

```
WebResource resource = client.resource("...");
List<User> users = resource.get(new GenericType<List<User>>(){});
```

See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27600246/2587435)

---

**UPDATE 2**

Since you are using the JAX-RS 2 client API, you can use the overloaded [`readEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity%28javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType%29), which accepts a `GenericType` argument also

```
List<User> user = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<User>>(){});
```

Comment: But I cannot modify Web Service. It sends me `[
  {
    "name": "Bobby",
    "status": "single"
  },
  ...
]`

Comment: And the resource method accepts `UserListWrapper` type?

Comment: Yes that's right. But I can make changes to wrapper. It is on the client.

Comment: What I don't get is if the service expects `{ "users" : [ {},{} ] }`, then why don't you just send it like that?

Comment: You seem to be presenting two different problems: one with sending and one with receiving. That is what's got me confused. Can you please clarify

Comment: No, server expects `[
  {
    "name": "Bobby",
    "status": "single"
  },
  ...
]` But I know only how to send `{
  "user": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "status": "single"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "status": "married"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Ah I see. Why don't you just send a `List<User>`? instead of `UserListWrapper`? If you are having problems sending the `List<User>`, can you should the code where you are making this request

Comment: I use wrapper also to get users from server. I need some wrapper to store the result.

Comment: You can use `List<User>` to deserialize also. Are you using the Jersey Client API to automatically deserialize, or are you using Jackson to deseraize?

Comment: I use Jersey Client API.