# Marshal/Un marshal List objects in Jersey JAX-RS using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Good Morning. Today morning when I am going through Jersey Entity providers `MessageBodyReader`s and `MessageBodyWriter`s I came across the following problem.

I want to write a resource method and client that returns a list of custom objects and media type is `application/xml`.  So I would like to use JAXB (I am new to JAXB). I was able to achieve this by writing my own extended `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`.  But I am afraid of the way I am following.  Just look at the way I implemented:

Resource method:

```
@Path("productlist/xml")
@GET
public RetObjects getProductsXml(){
    List<Product> pList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    pList.add(new Product("1","Dell latitude E6000",2900,500));
    pList.add(new Product("2","Xperia Z2",549,400));
    RetObjects obj = new RetObjects();
    obj.setObject(pList);
    return obj;
}
```

My custom objects:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="PRODUCT")
@XmlRootElement(name="product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    ...
    // rest of the fields, constructors, getters and setters
 }
```

Object that wraps my list of custom object:

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "products")
 @XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 public class RetObjects {

     @XmlElement(name = "product")
     private List<Product> object = null;

     public List<Product> getObject() {
         return object;
     }

     public void setObject(List<Product> object) {
         this.object = object;
     }
 }
```

`MessageBodyReader/Writer` are straight forward just using Jaxb unmarshaller and marshaller over the `RetObjects` object.

With this implementation it is working fine as expected and i am able to fetch the `RetObjects` wrapping the list of Products perfectly fine at client.

Here my question is, instead of wrapping my List of Products into a intermediate object, `RetObjects` in my case, couldn't I marshal and unmarshal List of Products object directly.  If I want to write another service that returns List of Orders, I need to wrap this with one more intermediate object.  What is the right approach to achieve this?  How could I do this without intermediate objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**First**

You don't *need* your own `MessageBodyWriter/Reader`. Jersey/JAX-RS alread has standard support for this. I would stick with the default, unless you have a *really, really* good reason for needed to whip up your own.

**Second**

We don't need the wrapper, you can simple return a [`GenericEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html). This will automatically wrap the elements in a "plural wrapper" element, i.e. `<product>` -> `<products>`.

```
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
GenericEntity<List<String>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Product>>(list) {};
Response response = Response.ok(entity).build();
```

For accepting a body in resource method, simply accepting `List<Product>` as an argument is enough. It will accept `<products><product/><product/></products>`

---

**UPDATE**

To retrieve the `List<Product>` on the client side, we should make use of `GenericType`. Se [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27643773/2587435).

Jersey 1

```
WebResource resource = client.resource("...");
List<Product> products = resource.get(new GenericType<List<Product>>(){});
```

Jersey 2/JAX-RS 2

```
Response response = ...
List<Product> products = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Product>>(){});
```

Comment: WRT second point, you are true @peeskillet.  When i am doing this, as you said I am getting <products><product></product></products>.  In this case how could I consume at client side in Java POJO objects?

Comment: I am not able to do response.readEntity(new RetObject2<List<Product>>(){}); I am getting compilation error saying readEntity(Class<T>) is not applicable for readEntity(RetObject2<List<Product>>(){}).  Here RetObject2 is a new generic class like RetObject2<T> with one field of type T.  Could you elaborate a bit.

Comment: Why Are you using `RepObject2`? It should be `GenericType`

Comment: The whole point of your question is to get rid of the wrapper object isn't it?

Comment: There is an overloaded [`readEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity%28javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType%29) which takes a `GenericType` argument.

Comment: See [`javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericType.html). It's an actual class. You are not supposed to provide your own "Generic type" :-) Sorry if I did not make that clear initially.

Comment: Thanks Peeskillet.  Its working fine.  I thought genericType is the abstract name you gave.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67653/discussion-between-user3694267-and-peeskillet).